# Adjust video playback color, contrast, and gamma on Mac?

Tags: video, movie

On Windows, the NVIDIA control panel provides some features that I use a lot when watching movies; you can adjust the gamma and other settings, such as dynamic contrast and color enhancement. I've been using these for a while as they make a big difference with Dark Movies. These settings, I assume are somehow magically "better" than directly adjusting settings in a video player software. The settings only affect video playback and not the Desktop colors or other applications. (This is not a critical feature for me to have but I'm just mentioning it so people know what I'm talking about)

What would be the equivalent to this on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your system's display setting and navigate to the color tab.
Click Calibrate and follow the process to set the display up as desired. In the end, it asks you for a name for the new display profile and saves it so you can easily switch between profiles.